# How to make Gatsby V5 project GDPR compliant

Tags: gatsby

I am using Gatsby V5 and I would like to know which plugin I should be using to make the site GDPR-compliant.  I checked all available GDPR plugins and they are not compliant with V5. Am I missing something?  I am using the gatsby-plugin-google-gtag to connect to google analytics.